# I am unable to update ubuntu with software updater or in about computer

Tags: 16.04, update-manager

I am on Ubutnu 16.04, When I go to update ubuntu on the software updater it just gives me an error and does not load. When I go to about computer there is no update button at all. If this info helps at all this did not happen tell a breaker flipped and cut my computer off.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Could you please edit your question with an ***error*** message added to your post.

Comment: Its was just an Ubuntu internal error and it wont pop up again or I would. When I click the updater it just stops loading and nothing happens does not show an error now?

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was install synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```